# mysql_num_rows() error when processing script

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, forms

I am adding a custom validation page to a WordPress Website I am working on.

Here is how the steps work to get a better understanding of the functional need.

1. visitor comes to the site and trys to sign up
2. visitor arrives to membership verification (this page will be a simple form with 3 fields that the user must enter their information as it appears on their membership card number.)
3. If incorrect info is provided the visitor receives an error message. If they enter successful information they will be redirected to the actual registration page of the WordPress website.

The issue.

I have built all my forms and everything is working except the validation process. Here is the script I am using

```
<?php
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['int_no']) || empty($_POST['firstnames']) || empty($_POST['surname'])) {
$error = "It appears that you have forgotten to fill out one of the form fields. Please fill out all requested information and try again.";
}
else
{
// Define $int_no $firstnames and $surname
$int_no=$_POST['int_no'];
$firstnames=$_POST['firstnames'];
$surname=$_POST['surname'];
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$int_no = stripslashes($int_no);
$firstnames = stripslashes($firstnames);
$surname = stripslashes($surname);
$int_no = mysql_real_escape_string($int_no);
$firstnames = mysql_real_escape_string($firstnames);
$surname = mysql_real_escape_string($surname);
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("IUEC-MEMBERS", $connection);
// SQL query to fetch information of registered Union Members and finds if there is a match.
$query = mysql_query("select * from login where surname='$surname' AND firstnames='$firstnames' AND int_no='$int_no'", $connection);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$int_no; // Initializing Session
header("location: http://iuec50.info/preview/online-membership-registration/"); // Redirecting To Other Page
} else {
$error = "We were not able to verify the information you provided. Please ensure you are entering your information as it appears on your International Card. If you continue to have issues please contact your Local.";
}
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
}
}
?>
```

I am getting an error when I enter the information and select the submit button.

The website URL in question is http://iuec50.info/preview/member-sign-up/

I am turing to the gurus that are within this site in hopes that you can shine some light on this issue.

Thank you all for your assistance.

Comment: and this error is...? you're simply assuming your db calls will never fail. That is extraordinarily **BAD** practice. Never assume success. Always assume failure, check for that failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: what error is throwing?

Comment: Oh, and thanks for your DB credentials...

Comment: Secure code right there,use proper Wp functions this is a hack waiting to happen

Comment: here is the current error message, I apologize. Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/iuec50/public_html/preview/wp-content/themes/IUEC50_2015/member-portal/membership-verification.php on line 26

Comment: thanks marc, missed that, in such a hurry I guess as this is the last thing I need to do before launch.

Comment: This means the query fails,make sure the table and column names exist

Comment: This code is a throwback to the bad-old-days when PHP deserved it's reputation for poor code quality. If you PHP version is up-to-date, you should not need `stripslashes()` at all, as the PHP functionality that adds slashes automatically no longer exists. The `mysql_xxx()` functions are also considered obsolete and are deprecated. If you're connecting to the DB for yourself you should be using `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. However, Wordpress has its own database API as well, so maybe you should just use that?

Comment: I grabbed this code from a tutorial, unfortunatly with the amount of turorials out there it can at times be hard to establish what is the right one to use. Once they get past this specific form the rest is all handled by WordPress, I just need to verify the information provided on this form

Comment: so basically I need to go back and write this over again? does anyone have a better tutorial they can direct me to by chance. It seems like an easy task, someone enters 3 fields, a php script verifies the content from a mysql database and then returns either an error message or sends them to a page if info is correct. any advice would be gratefully appreciated.